# How to overwrite WooCommerce total shipping costs in function.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a function to calculate total shipping costs in my functions.php

```
.
.
if($weight < 5){
   if($land == "DE"){ $shipping_costs = 4.99;}
   if($land == "AT"){ $shipping_costs = 8.89;}
   if($land == "CH"){ $shipping_costs = 12.70;}
}
.
.
```

How can i overwrite the total shipping costs in cart and checkout with the new $shipping_costs value?

Comment: You nee, to use the hook `woocommerce_package_rates` like [in those threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+woocommerce_package_rates)

Comment: @ LoicTheAztec Got it, thank you!!